# Log into Joomla 3 without a Password

Tags: php, joomla, authentication, joomla3.0

Does anyone have any insight into how this could be accomplished?

I figure that it may be possible to mess with the session unless there is already a built in function that could be used to do this.

If you need more information just let me know, I would be happy to provide it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The following code snippet should load a user based on their id from the database and then log them in for the visitor making the request. It does not require their password. That being said, I do hope that you are authenticating this in some way. (And I have only tested this on the front-end of the site.)

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();

$q = "SELECT * FROM `#__users` WHERE id = ".$id;
$user = $db->setQuery($q)->loadAssoc();

JPluginHelper::importPlugin( 'user' );
$dispatcher = JDispatcher::getInstance();

// Initiate log in
$options = array('action' => 'core.login.site', 'remember' => false);
$results = $dispatcher->trigger('onUserLogin', array($user, $options));
```

Comment: I will try this later today.  I appreciate the reply.

Comment: Also, as for authentication, I am authenticating from another URL using an oauth handshake.  While not the _most_ secure, it works for the site I am working with.

Comment: That's good! I've used this before for a couple different purposes, so I know that there are good reasons to do so, especially for single sign on purposes. I just like to leave security reminders around in case!

Comment: It looks like the session is properly created in the database but I'm not actually logged in after testing it.  I think this might be related to the php session set by Joomla?

Comment: If you are authenticating with the oauth I wold jsut write an authentication plugin to login correctly. https://github.com/Buddhima/Joomla-HttpLogin-plugin might give you some ideas.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @Elin I will play around with this.